# Unable to get list of URLs

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to use the below script. Why it is not retrieving a list of URLs for this site? It works on other sites.

Initially I thought the problem was that is was not allowed by `robots.txt`, but it is not returning a error when I run it.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse
import mechanize

url = "https://www.danmurphys.com.au"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

urls = [url]
visited =[url]

print 
while len(urls)>0:
try:
    br.open(urls[0])
    urls.pop(0) 
    for link in br.links():
        #print link
        #print "The base url is :" + link.base_url # just check there is this applicable to all sites.
        #print "The url is: " + link.url # This gives generally just the page name
        new_url = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url,link.url)
        b1 = urlparse.urlparse(new_url).hostname
        b2 = urlparse.urlparse(new_url).path
        new_url = "http://"+ b1 + b2

        if new_url not in visited and urlparse.urlparse(url).hostname in new_url:
            visited.append(new_url)
            urls.append(new_url)
            print new_url
except:
    print "error"
    urls.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use something else to scrape that URL such as [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) with [scrapyJS](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash) or [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org/) as the Mechanize library doesn't work with Javascript.

```
r = br.open(urls[0])
html = r.read()
print html
```

and you'll see the output:

```
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the page content.</noscript>
```